# How to clear all the events from secondary calendar using Java?

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I'm able to use [clear API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/clear) to clear all the events of the primary calendar, but the same is not working fine with the newly created calendar (secondary calendar) and I'm getting following error.

```
{
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Cannot clear primary calendar."
}
```

I assume this API will not work for newly created calendar (secondary calendar), please confirm. Also, please suggest what is the right way of clearing all the events from the calendar that I have created.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: I would assume you didn't set the calendar ID correctly, but without seeing your code, no-one can know